# PHP Switch: Access other case within current case

Tags: php

I have the following code which is not very smart. Is there a way to do it in a better way?
My var can have the following string: approval, calc, or approval,calc

```
foreach ($objRole['conditions'] as $conditionId => $objCondition) {
    switch ($objCondition->calculation) {
        case 'approval':
            // LOGIC A
        break;
        case 'calc':
            // LOGIC B
        break;
        case 'approval,calc':
            // LOGIC A + B

            // Here I have repeated the same code from approval and from calc switch case.
            // Is there a way to run the code from approval and calc so I must not repeat 
            // it here again?
            break;
    }
}
```

Cheers all for help!

Comment: Normally to avoid code duplication you'd extract the code to a function and call it from both places

Answer (score 0):

If you change to a pair of `if` statements, and for each one you say if it's not some value then do this...

```
foreach ($objRole['conditions'] as $conditionId => $objCondition) {
    if ( $objCondition->calculation != 'calc' ) {
        // LOGIC A
    }
    if ( $objCondition->calculation != 'approval' ) {
        // LOGIC B
    }
}
```

so for `approval` and `approval,calc` it will do logic A and for `calc` and `approval,calc` it will do logic B.

A more common approach would be to move the logic to functions and call them as appropriate.

Comment: I know OP only gives 3 variations, so your answer is correct. But it removes every flexibility from the code. If in the future a variation `'bring the boss coffee'` is added, a switch only needs a new `case`, this foreach will need a lot more `if`s.

Comment: @Michel, people sometimes have to code for what is going on now.  How can you code for every possible eventuality, what if it's converted to a whole list of possibilities and combinations - how would that be dealt with?

Comment: Thank you, never thought about this approach

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use functions and call those from your switch:

```
switch ($objCondition->calculation) {
        case 'approval':
            logic_A();
        break;
        case 'calc':
            logic_B();
        break;
        case 'approval,calc':
            logic_A();
            logic_B();
            break;
    }

function logic_A(){...}
function logic_B(){...}
```